# Customizing the product addon section in woocommerce?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am working on an ecommerce project I have added the product addons on the product page with four options. I want to add a radio button for the first upload option and when user selects that option I want to give the user the upload option. I am not sure how to do this, which files i will have to edit !to add this functionality ?

Do I have to change the functions.php in the themes folder of wordpress ?

[image]

Comment: We have no idea how to answer this question. We don't know what your code looks like; so we can't help you interface with it.

Comment: If you want a dirty solution I bet you could do that with some html and javascript skills pretty easily. If you want a 'proper' solution I think you should understand the wordpress API. Anyway as mevius mentioned above please provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/about/) is limited only by your imagination

And it trully is - there are thousands of different plugins, themes, add-ons, etc. for your WordPress. Without knowing what exactly are you talking about it is just a **shot in the dark**.

> I want to add a radio button for the first upload option and when user selects that option I want to give the user the upload option.

The following code snippet does the job for you (add style, more functionality)

```
<form id="form_1" type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded' method="post">
    <label for="product_1">Product 1</label>
        <input form="form_1" type="radio" value="1" name="products" id="product_1" />
        <input form="form_2" type="file" name="products" id="product_1_upload" style="display: none;" /><br>
    <label for="product_2">Product 2</label><input form="form_1" type="radio" value="2" name="products" id="product_2" /><br>
    <label for="product_3">Product 3</label><input form="form_1" type="radio" value="3" name="products" id="product_3" /><br>
</form>
<form id="form_2" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'></form>

<button id="form_submit"/>Submit</button>

<script>

    $('input[type=radio][name=products]').change(function()
    {
        if ($('#product_1').prop('checked') == true)
        {
            $('#product_1').css({'display' : 'none'});
            $('#product_1_upload').css({'display' : 'inline-block'});
        }
        else
        {
            $('#product_1').css({'display' : 'inline-block'});
            $('#product_1_upload').css({'display' : 'none'});
        }
    });

    $('#form_submit').click(function()
    {           
        if ($('#product_1_upload').val() || $('#product_1').prop('checked') == true)
        {
            $('#form_2').submit();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#form_1').submit();
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Also mentioned the comments above, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty (to save some reputation of yours).